# Accessing Apache's unique_id from java code

Tags: java, apache, request, unique-id

I need to access the mod_unique_id attribute for a request to my apache server. Is there a way to do that in the java code, something like `request.UNIQUE_ID`? I read through [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html) already and couldn't find anything, I also didn't entirely understand the article, so I may have missed something. If anyone could clear this up for me, that would be great!

Answer (score 3):

You could add the UNIQUE_ID as a request header

Apache config:

```
    RequestHeader set UNIQUE_ID "%{UNIQUE_ID}e"
```

Then write some Java code to read this header:

```
    request.getHeader("UNIQUE_ID");
```

Answer (score 2):

in */etc/apache2/apache2.conf*:

```
<IfModule unique_id_module>
    SetEnvIf X-Requestid "^$" no_request_id
    RequestHeader set X-Requestid %{UNIQUE_ID}e env=no_request_id
</IfModule>
```

- add the symlink in modes-enabled:
  `unique_id.load -> ../mods-available/unique_id.load`
- in the shell, execute `sudo a2enmod headers`
- restart apache

in Java Code:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
String uniqueId = request.getHeader("x-requestid");
```

Comment: please change `X-Requestid` to `X-Request-ID` just not to make confusion